# Ler arquivos duas vezes

Tags: c#

Tenho um projeto **Asp.Net MVC** em `.Net Framework 4.0`, com `Entity Framework 5.0`.

Recebo vários arquivos em um método `POST` e preciso transformá-los em `byte[]` para salvar no Banco de Dados (`VARBINARY(MAX)` - SQL Server) e depois ler seu conteúdo.

Estou usando o `BinaryReader` para ler os `bytes` do arquivo inteiro e tem funcionado perfeitamente se uso ele antes do `StreamReader`, mas ao tentar usar o `StreamReader` depois para ler as linhas do arquivo é como se houvesse sido dado um `Dispose()` no `postedFile.InputStream`.

O interessante é que se eu inverter a ordem, lendo as linhas antes com `StreamReader` e depois tentando usar o `BinaryReader`, então este último também não funciona por conta do mesmo motivo.

Sei que ambos de alguma forma implementam a interface `IDisposable`, e estão usando o mesmo `postedFile.InputStream` (que também é `Disposable`), mas o que não vejo sentido é dar um `Dispose()` também no `InputStream` e não **apenas** no objeto em si que o está usando.

Segue trecho do código:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    var postedFile = Request.Files[i];
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower();
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

    // Ler bytes do arquivo
    byte[] fileBytes;
    using (var reader2 = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
    {
        fileBytes = reader2.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength); // Funciona perfeitamente e retorna o resultado correto.
    }

    // Ler linhas do arquivo
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream))
    {
         var header = reader.ReadLine(); // Erro nessa linha! header = null.
         // Código continua...
    }

    // Código continua...
}
```

Comment: Na verdade não funcionou, o Length do InputStream está perfeito quando entro no BinaryReader, mas quando saio dele é 0. Como se tivesse dado um Dispose() mesmo, mas acho que é justamente isso que acontece. A solução está no .Net Framework 4.5, mas estou usando 4.0: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=VS.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente, pelo que entendi nas pesquisas, tando o `BinaryReader` quanto o `StreamReader` quando saem do contexto do `using`, fazem automaticamente um "auto" `Dispose()` e também de todos os que são `IDisposable` usados dentro.

Isso foi melhorado na versão 4.5 do .Net Framework, [incluindo a opção `leaveOpen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=VS.110).aspx) no contrutor do `StreamReader` por exemplo, que quando `true` mantem os objetos abertos.

Tive que montar uma solução diferente para mim:

```
byte[] fileBytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Copia o InputStream para o MemoryStream 'ms'.
    postedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms); 

    // Reposiciona para o início o ponteiro de leitura que foi para o final após a realização da cópia.
    ms.Position = 0; 

    // Crio 'ms2' que será 'morto' depois que passar pelo BinaryReader
    using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream())
    {
         ms.CopyTo(ms2);
         ms2.Position = 0;

         using (var br = new BinaryReader(ms2))
         {
              fileBytes = br.ReadBytes((int)ms2.Length);
         }
    }

    // A Position mudou pois foi feita a cópia para 'ms2'
    ms.Position = 0;

    // Aqui 'ms' será lido e 'morrerá'
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        var header = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Fonte:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8462655/4720858

Answer (score 1):

#### O problema está no `using`

Repare que você está fazendo dois `using` em cima do mesmo stream, ainda que indiretamente:

```
using (new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
{
}
// Dispose

using (new StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream))
{
}
// Dispose
```

Então, sim, o `postedFile.InputStream` vai estar fechado/apagado após o primeiro `using`.

#### Resolvendo com `byte[]` e `MemoryStream`

```
for ( var i = 0 ; i < Request.Files.Count ; i++ )
{
    // Bytes do arquivo
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[postedFile.ContentLength];
    postedFile.InputStream.Read( fileBytes , 0 , fileBytes.Length );

    // Grava dados no banco
    //     A partir de fileBytes

    // Ler linhas do arquivo
    using ( var reader = new StreamReader( new MemoryStream( fileBytes ) ) )
    {
        var header = reader.ReadLine();
        // Seu código
    }

    // Código continua...
}
```

Dessa forma os dados não são fechados pelo `using`, e você pode usar repetidamente o array `fileBytes`, cujo qual não tem `Dispose()` e você nunca perde a referência.

Porém, fica com dados duplicados em memória, por todo o tempo de processamento da requisição, o que é um desperdício.

Para liberar a memória do `postedFile.InputStream` o quanto antes, você pode fazer um

```
using ( postedFile.InputStream )
    ;
```

logo após o `Read()`. Incomum, mas eficaz.

---

### Outras considerações

#### HttpInputStream e performance

A propriedade `InputStream` em `Request.Files` (classe `HttpPostedFile`) não é um stream exatamente convencional. Trata-se da classe `HttpInputStream`, que internamente utilizada ainda `HttpRawUploadedContent` como armazenamento, de forma a lidar com dados em memória **ou** dados em arquivos temporários, de forma transparente.

Isso mais a questão que no namespace `System.Web` a preocupação é toda com performance e acessos simultâneos, paralelos, é algo esperado que dados efêmeros sejam descartados o mais rápido possível. O `using` apenas está fazendo isso ocorrer antes.

A sacada aí é que o `using` está agindo, indiretamente, num dado que foi criado fora, *antes* do próprio `using`.

#### MemoryStream para dados "pequenos"

Uma solução para o seu problema é ler todo o conteúdo do arquivo para um `MemoryStream`, e de lá fazer leituras repetidas (como no exemplo acima).

É uma pena duplicar os dados temporariamente (e ainda mais se forem grandes), mas é o jeito para lidar com essa questão.

#### Arquivos temporários para dados grandes

Porém, se você tem expectativa de receber arquivos grandes, que sejam percentuais inteiros da RAM do servidor, daí a implementação de `HttpRawUploadedContent` dá uma dica: não deixe esses dados em memória, coloque em arquivos temporários.

---

[Códigos fonte de HttpInputStream e HttpRawUploadedContent](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/HttpInputStream@cs/1305376/HttpInputStream@cs)

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua resposta. Toda a informação foi muito bem colocada por você! Sei que o link pode me ajudar, mas infelizmente ele pode quebrar, então seria espetacular se você pudesse exemplificar um pequeno trecho de código...

Comment: Outra questão é que infelizmente não tenho permissão para gravar arquivos nos diretórios do servidor, então `HttpRawUploadedContent` acredito que não poderia ser usado no meu caso, mas eu não conhecia e gostei muito, e também acredito que pode ajudar muito outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Comment: `HttpRawUploadedContent` seria só para inspirar, já que é uma classe `internal` e portanto indisponível. Coloquei o exemplo, mas vou complementar a resposta, que acho que o problema está no `using.`

Comment: Veja como ficou.